# MovieClip sight in the top of the layers but appears behind other movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Hello i have a sight in basic game that Im trying to develop and i have the sight movieclip layer in the top of the layers and the sight appears in front of other objects but then i have  balloons that are entering in the stage that I need to shoot and the sight appears behind the balloons, has anyone had this problem and know how to solve it??
I have my balloon in other swf and i load it, its possible when i load the balloon in actionscript say to the balloon go behind others movieclips??

Comment: Nobody is going to help you out if your question is *this* vague. Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding children to the stage with addChild(...) at runtime then those will go on top of everything inside that parent.  You can just add your sight to the top again by:

```
var mySight:MovieClip;
addChild(mySight);//adds the sight on top of other elements inside this parent

//if you still have items on top that means the parent DisplayObjectContainer might have elements on top of it
```

Comment: Thank you..it worked with all of draws :)! but the baloons that are Loaders objects the sight is behind like before!

Comment: @oscar are these elements on the stage or nested in movieclips?